# wrong start up disk

Tags: grubrescue

I left a disk in my dvd drive and received an error message:
'attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue> rescue

What should I do next to restore the system?

I have tried this sequence of commands

error: attempt to read or write outside of disk ‘hd0’
 ls
 (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (fdO)
 ls (hd0)
 (hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
 ls (fd0)
 (fd0): Filesystem is unknown.
 error: failure reading sector 0x2 from ‘fd0’
 ls (hd0, msdos1)
 (hd0,msdos1) : Filesystem is ext2

> set boot= (hd0,msdos1)
>   set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
>
> > insmod normal normal
> >     error: attempt to read or write outside of disk ‘hd0’.

Suggestions please

Comment: Check the BIOS Setup, and set the HDD as the first boot device. Did you unplugged your HDD?. The UUID could be changed when the HDD is plugged in again.

Comment: What happens if you boot the computer, after you have removed the DVD disk?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DVD and reboot.

Optionally, enter BIOS set-up and change the boot drive priority.

Comment: GTRONIK and David Foerster - I have reset the BIOS several times but return to grub rescue each time.  The BIOS page is not one I am used to as it allows SELECT  but gives no option to save, only BOOT after selection. Is there an alternative to get my computer up and running?

Comment: @user572284: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @user572284: Please refer to the manufacturer's manual for how to use the BIOS configuration as it's unrelated to Ubuntu and therefore outside of the scope of Ask *Ubuntu*. Alternatively you can ask about that over on [SU]. Thanks.